# Friendly name for anycast IP with google Loadbalancer

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, cdn

I have created a CDN  for our google cloud storage bucket. Everything works fine. Though we had to change our code and change our old loadbalancer friendly name with the ip address.

Would it be a little overkill to add a google cloud dns in front of our anycast ip adress ? It would be helpful to refer to our loadbalancer with a human readable name instead of the ip. But we dont want to add any latency

Answer (score 1):

Overkill? Not at all. Unnecessary? Maybe. Adds more complexity? Yes. Latency? Not really.

What you need to be aware is that you're adding an additional point of failure into your system, and whether you can offset this point of failure sufficiently.

For example, if something happens to your DNS resolution, then you can no longer talk to your load balancer. This is *probably* OK, because if your DNS fails then chances are a bunch of other stuff would fail as well.

You're also adding a layer of caching. This can slow down your time to implement a change, if you need to change this in the future. Maybe this is OK, maybe it isn't. Only you can answer that (as you know your infrastructure).

Latency-wise, you should be fine. You will be doing a lookup only when the TTL expires, which will be set based on whatever you have set. DNS lookups are typically very fast.